# Trying to output special characters - Android keyboard development

Tags: android, android-studio, keyboard

I want to output characters such as **Ċ, ċ, Ġ** etc..

I have the following codes for **Ċ**:

```
U+0010A
UNICODE
&#x010A;
HEX CODE
&#266;
HTML CODE
&Cdot;
```

At the moment I have a line of code in a xml file:

```
<key android:codes="-300" android:keyLabel="&#266;"/>
```

Can I use something like :

```
case -300:
     ic.sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.x));
     break;
```

Am I on the right track or completely going about this wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save them in xml using html-code but, this is mostly not needed if they are in the UTF-8 notation, actual characters will also do:

```
<string name="my_string">&#65;</string>
```

Or, you can call setText() with unicode on the TextView:

```
textView.setText("\u266b");
```

here this will help you more :
two website that I personally use to write in Icelandic, every single character you rae looking for is listed there

[Characters table website 1](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref)

[Characters table website 2](http://unicode-table.com/en/#00FD)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Those links with the characters are excellent!